# The Authorization header is missing

Tags: .net, azure, api, postman

I am getting this error :{"error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":"Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is missing."}} whenever I am trying to test my API that is

**https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionID}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/{location}/publishers/{publisherName}/artifacttypes/vmimage/offers/{offer}/skus?api-version=2019-03-01**

Can anybody suggest a solution how to set authentication header in postman or API Tester.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Management REST API - "Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is provided in an invalid format."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39822874/azure-management-rest-api-authentication-failed-the-authorization-header-i)

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to get a Bearer token in order to use for Authentication header would be to use `az cli`.

```
$token =  az account get-access-token | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Then by accessing `$token.accesstoken` you will have string as shown below.

[image]

You can use this Token then with your API call as a `Bearer` token

```
$headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $token.accesstoken" }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Authorization` is the part of `HTTP Header` and generally it is token which is Base64 encoded.  In Postman, you can add it by clicking on "Headers" button.

[image: This is where Authorization is set in Postman]

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up and configure Postman to obtain an Azure Active Directory token.

[A full walk though is covered here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/digital-twins/how-to-configure-postman.md) - screen shots below for quick reference.

[image: Getting a token using Postman]

From the docs - a sample token request form.

[image: Token request form]

Answer (score 1):

This is a guide to use `curl` to get the https://medium.com/@mauridb/calling-azure-rest-api-via-curl-eb10a06127.

You can replace the place holder to your service principal in this command.

`curl -vX POST -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=${spClientId}&client_secret=${spSecret}&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.azure.com%2F" https://login.microsoftonline.com/${spTenantId}/oauth2/token)`